# Errors with trying to make a minecraft plugin (Ecilpse)

Tags: java, eclipse, minecraft, bukkit

I have imported the latest version of spigot-api to my project, but when i write `import org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin;`, I get a error saying 
`The type org.bukkit.plugin.java.JavaPlugin is not accessible.`
I need help.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RESOLVED: Switching from JavaSE-12 to JavaSE-1.8 worked

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure you imported it correctly: Right click on your project > Properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > Add **External** JARs...

If you already did that, make use of Eclipses quick fix feature. Add `extends JavaPlugin` to your public class, so it looks like this:

```
//JavaPlugin will be flagged as an error
public class MainClass extends JavaPlugin {
...
}
```

Now hover over `JavaPlugin`, a small menu should pop up, suggesting possible solutions with the first one being `Import 'JavaPlugin' (org.bukkit.plugin.java)`, Click on it and it should import the JavaPlugin object

If both solutions don't work, I'd either suggest updating Java or use Maven, it manages your dependencies **and** there should be Eclipse/Maven addons for Minecraft plugin developers, to help make the start easier